# Bash script in Github Actions "[[: not found"

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I've seen a couple posts on stackoverflow about an error in bash scripts causing the error:

```
[[: not found
```

I have tried everything to remedy this, but nothing's worked.

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1 
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: bash ./run test_ts_node
      shell: bash
```

I found the `shell` yml option but it seems to not help.

My shebangs are `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of info missing from your question. What is causing the error exactly ? Do you have a line number in the error message ? Could you show the incriminated `./run` script ?

Comment: I would replace it with `[`, it's compatible with other shells and there's nothing you couldn't do with `[` and CLI tools that `[[` can do.

Comment: Presumably the `run` command uses the wrong shell, `sh`, rather than `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the message that `dash`, which is the default `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu, gives when you try to use `[[`, which is a bashism.  There's something in your environment that is either invoking `sh` explicitly or implicitly and expecting it to be `bash`.

On my system, `dash` prints the name of the script (or `sh` if it's a `sh -c` invocation) and so it may be helpful to look at that output and try to determine the cause of the problem.  You may also want to try running your shell script with `-x` to see if you can figure out which command it invokes that is causing the problem.  The logs should show you which step is causing the problem, so if it's `npm ci`, then that will appear as a separate step in GitHub Actions and you'll be able to pin down the cause more definitively.

Also note that Git invokes `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`, so if you're scripting anything with a Git command that invokes the shell, then you'll need to avoid writing bashisms in that scripting.

It isn't otherwise obvious where your problem is come from, so without more information, we really can't say definitively where your problem is.

Comment: By the way you can change the shell in GitHub Actions with the `shell` field on a step ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell)).